# Create many different elements with jQuery - append

Tags: jquery, append

```
    var i1 = $("<input type='radio' class='11' value='11' /><input type='radio' class='2' value='2' />");
    var i2 = $("<input type='radio' class='111' value='111' /><input type='radio' class='12'  value='12' /><input type='radio' class='21' value='21' /><input type='radio' class='3' value='3' />");
    var i3 = $("<input type='radio' class='1111' value='1111' /><input type='radio' class='121'  value='121' /><input type='radio' class='13' value='13' /><input type='radio' class='31' value='31' /><input type='radio' class='22' value='22' /><input type='radio' class='4' value='4' />");
    var i4 = $("<input type='radio' class='11111' value='11111' /><input type='radio' class='122'  value='122' /><input type='radio' class='212' value='212' /><input type='radio' class='23' value='23' /><input type='radio' class='32' value='32' /><input type='radio' class='14' value='14' />");
    var i5 = $("<input type='radio' class='111111' value='111111' /><input type='radio' class='123'  value='123' /><input type='radio' class='132' value='132' /><input type='radio' class='213' value='213' /><input type='radio' class='222' value='222' /><input type='radio' class='33' value='33' /><input type='radio' class='24' value='24' />");
    b.append(i1);
```

How can I make this append increment i1 i2 i3 i4...

I want to click on the first "+1" to show the two options is i1.Second click "+1" show the i2. and i3 i4 i5 i6...

and click the "-1" this i1.remove() i2 i3 remove...

and upload/insert switch after "+1" it problems..

*Sorry for my bad English.*

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huZzq/1/)

Comment: Why not use an array instead of five independent variables?

Comment: Can you help me to fix and save it? im code idiot....

Answer (score 4):

Put the object in some array and use `each` loop to iterate through them.

```
 var ix = [];
   ix.push( $("<input type='radio' class='11' value='11' /><input type='radio' class='2' value='2' />"));
   ix.push( $("<input type='radio' class='111' value='111' /><input type='radio' class='12'  value='12' /><input type='radio' class='21' value='21' /><input type='radio' class='3' value='3' />"));
   ix.push( $("<input type='radio' class='1111' value='1111' /><input type='radio' class='121'  value='121' /><input type='radio' class='13' value='13' /><input type='radio' class='31' value='31' /><input type='radio' class='22' value='22' /><input type='radio' class='4' value='4' />"));

$.each(ix, function(index, obj) { 
  b.append(obj);
});
```

Comment: @Adil, I was wrong actually, `append()` supports arrays of DOM elements but not arrays of jQuery objects. Since each object contains several DOM elements, it is not even practical to build an array of DOM elements instead of an array of jQuery objects. Your original answer was better. My apologies.

Comment: No worries, I also did not realize that.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi oh come on you guys please help me

Comment: @DongYifei, I'm afraid I do not understand. How is this answer not helping you? It does answer your question.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi sorry my english so bad,  i need to click on the first "+1" show two options i1, and the second click the "+1" it i2, and i3 i4 i5...